# Access to a workspace variable from a class

Tags: matlab

I have a class, in the standard arrangement:

```
classdef ClassName
   properties
      PropertyName
   end
   methods
      function obj = ClassName(arg1,...)
         obj.PropertyName = arg1;
         ...
      end
      function ordinaryMethod(obj,arg1,...)
         ...
      end
   end
end
```

Containing a large array of functions, that I call in a separate script. The separate script generates a cell-array, which is updated with each iteration (storing results). With my current setup, I am not able to explicitly pass the cell-array to a function in the class - but I need the variable to be available for use there.

How can I do this without saving the cell-array as a .mat file after each update and constantly loading it every time a call is made? Can somebody show an example?

Comment: "With my current setup, I am not able to explicitly pass the cell-array to a function in the class" Why not? It seems that your code structure is wrong then. If function A creates a cell array and calls a method in your class, then function A has the cell array available to pass to the method. No?

Comment: @Cris Luengo You're right. I'm new to this. Is there a way to create a function that simply makes the variable available in the class workspace?

Comment: Would evalin be suitable for this?

Comment: You can use `evalin` for this, but `evalin` is a patch, not good practice to use. It will make your code slower and harder to debug. Please think about how to reorganize your code instead. By the way, there's no class workspace, each function (method) has its own workspace.

Comment: Agreed `evalin` is not ideal. It would be much better to explicitly pass the information needed from the cell array to a function in the class. You could pass the whole cell array, or some information from it if passing in the whole thing results in performance issues. If you share a reproducible example someone can help more specifically!

Comment: @verbatross: MATLAB uses lazy copying, which means that there are no performance issues with passing large data to a function — it doesn’t get copied.